# mixing pure ruby on rails and ember pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm starting a new web app that will be developed in Ember. Like any web site there will be a lot of static pages like the home page, an about page, authentication pages etc.

What is the best approach? To do the static pages with standard RoR and have one page where the app is running, or do every page with Ember?

And if the Ember app is on page "theapp.html.erb" how do I tell the Router to kick in only on that page?

Comment: You should check ember-rails repo

Comment: That got me almost there, though not entirely. Sprockets sometimes doesn't behave as I would expect. Ended up using the rootElement of Em.Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would develop the website with Ruby on Rails. Then on the page where the Ember app should live, I would include the necessary JavaScript. This way the Ember app is only kicked of at the correct page.

Comment: I'll use the mix of both indeed. I ended up using the rootElement attribute of the Ember.Application and that seems to work fine.